# Why did YouTube put a type= attribute in iframe for embedded video?

Tags: html, youtube

When going to YouTube, it gives a embed code such as

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player"
class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/QRvVzaQ6i8A?rel=0">
</iframe>
```

Note that the

```
type="text/html"
```

is not valid html. There's no such attribute for iframe tag.

could anyone explain why google put that? I guess it's for some practical reason, but i couldn't guess what.

PS you can get the embed code by going here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRvVzaQ6i8A

Comment: amazing. Looks like Google fixed it. Now, it no longer include the type=.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is a mistake from Google itself. I suspect a mistake. It was not part of HTML4, and it is not part of HTML5. You can safely ignore it and remove it.

on the type attribute topic: The [type on the object element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/obsolete.html#type-23) is conforming but obsolete. It has never been really used by browsers to guess the content of the URI served.

Comment: nice link. I tend to concur. I wonder if any googler would say something about it?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a mistake, it's the embed code for the [HTML5 Youtube Player](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html).

When it comes to validating HTML, you have to remember that HTML5 allows the content author to use non-standard elements and attributes and the document should still work. Additionally, non-standard markup that becomes popular enough can be documented and become an extension to the HTML5 spec.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was from a while back, but there's a helpful explanation from a YouTube developer here: http://groups.google.com/group/youtube-api-gdata/browse_thread/thread/f492756804cd481a#msg_29fb6e74326f7a5c.

In short,

- the ‘type’ and ‘class’ attributes are now gone

however, non-standard frameborder and allowfullscreen attributes have been added:

- the ‘frameborder="0"’ is for “certain IE versions” (could be replaced by CSS if necessary?)
- the ‘allowfullscreen' is for “certain Firefox HTML5 playback scenarios”