# Iframe not displaying content

Tags: html, firefox, iframe, youtube, embed

This snippet was gathered from a random youtube video:

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/http://www.youtube.com/v/gnrvYsZWR1c?rel=0" title="YouTube video player" type="text/html" frameborder="0" height="390" width="480"></iframe>
```

Again, a little easier to read:

```
<iframe
class="youtube-player" 
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/http://www.youtube.com/v/gnrvYsZWR1c?rel=0" 
title="YouTube video player" 
type="text/html" 
frameborder="0" 
height="390" 
width="480"
></iframe>
```

It is not displaying the embedded youtube in Firefox 15.0.1 on Windows or Linux.   Is there a problem with how this snippet is constructed, or is Firefox simply not displaying iframe content?

Comment: Also do not use the type attribute http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800227/why-did-youtube-put-a-type-attribute-in-iframe-for-embedded-video

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iframes are fine with FF

There is something wrong with your video link.

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/http://www.youtube.com/v/gnrvYsZWR1c?rel=0
```

Should read

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/gnrvYsZWR1c?rel=0
```

or

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/gnrvYsZWR1c?rel=0
```

So this code works:

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/gnrvYsZWR1c?rel=0"
 title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" height="390" width="480"></iframe>
```

Comment: I couldn't see the forest for the trees.  Thanks.